# How to read monthly returns data into python?

Tags: python, pandas

After reading this data frame successfully into python with :

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Desktop/IBM.csv")
```

I try to get monthly returns from this data from using this line of code:

```py
IBM_monthly_returns = df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
```

Please help

[image]

Full Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKCW6.png

Comment: You have tagged `python` but you say you read the `df` in `R`.

Comment: thanks yes it is for python sorry

Comment: OP is using the pandas library, added the tag.

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be stock data from Yahoo Finance or similar that was downloaded to csv. In order to apply resample you may need to do a couple of things

Make sure the date is in datetime format

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Index by date:

```
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
```

then you can run:

```
IBM_monthly_returns = df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
print(IBM_monthly_returns.head())
```

Note: you can skip the two steps if you read the data directly using pandas_reader, for instance:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
df= pdr.get_data_yahoo('IBM', '20190101')
IBM_monthly_returns = df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
print(IBM_monthly_returns.head())
```